# How to update an array of _ids in MongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of _ids which contains MongoDB's ObjectIds. Now I want to update all the documents of those _ids at once. I have tried this way, but it is updating only the first element of the array:

```
    Product.update({
         _id: { "$in": req.body.idArray }
    }, req.body.payload).then((product) => {
        console.log('Array of ids updated', product);
        res.json({ status: true, product: product })
    });
```

How to update all the _ids present in the array? Also, would there be a significant lag (which apparently I faced) if I update them each?

Comment: Yes, Sir! I agree and I have marked it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

```
  Product.update(
{
     _id: { "$in": req.body.idArray }
}, 
req.body.payload,
{"multi": true}).then((product) => {
    console.log('Array of ids updated', product);
    res.json({ status: true, product: product })
});
```